# Large LEGO Minifig Styles

Tags: piece-information, minifigures, part-identification

I'm pretty sure the LEGO figure on the right is the daughter from a 1977 set [Nurse and Child](http://brickset.com/sets/276-1/Nurse-and-Child). But what about this style of jumbo minifig on the left with arms and legs that bend? When was that from? It might be from a LEGO Basic set? What different styles of minifigs has LEGO produced over the years?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The figure on the left is generally referred to as a [Fabuland figure](http://peeron.com/cgi-bin/invcgis/psearch?query=Fabuland%20Figure&limit=none), although I believe that the entire Fabuland line actually featured animals. There were a few basic sets released in the 80s that included human Fabuland-style figures. That one is probably from this [fire engine](http://peeron.com/inv/sets/392-2):

[image: 392-2]

Before the introduction of the Minifig in 1978, there was the Maxifig that you noted in your question:

[image: Nurse and Child]

The precursor to the modern minifig was added in 1975:

[image: Inflexible figures]

LEGO released a [history of the minifig](http://cache.lego.com/r/club/-/media/club/markets/us/inside%20scoop/history%20of%20minifig/history%20of%20the%20minifigure.pdf) that you might find interesting.

In addition to the traditional minifig, you may also come across Technic figures which were around for a time.

[image: Technic figure]

There were also the [Creator figures](http://peeron.com/cgi-bin/invcgis/psearch?query=Creator%20Figure&limit=none) that were only around briefly in the early 2000s:

[image: creator figure]

Comment: The Creator figure look very similar to the ones in the [Jack Stone](http://lego.wikia.com/wiki/Jack_Stone_(Theme)) theme.

Comment: The link for the timeline is broken, not even a 404 page appears.